# Lemond Revolution - Upgrading 9s Cassette to 11 Speed

Tags: trainer

I currently have a 9 speed cassette on my Lemond Revolution trainer. I just purchased new bike which is 11 speed and want to use it on my trainer. Is there a way I can do this? I have looked everywhere for an eleven speed upgrade kit from Lemond, but they no longer make them.

[image]

Comment: Its just a funny-shaped wheel, as far as the bike is concerned.    What's stopping you fitting an 11 speed cassette to this - the freehub body should be the same size, and the chainrings are closer together.    Your other option is to stick the 9 speed bike in the trainer permanently.

Comment: @Criggie, Shimano & SRAM road 11 speed uses a wider freehub body. Mountain's the same though.

Answer (score 5):

The Lemond manual might answer this question with an odd footnote on page 19, which states "11-speed components will fit, but may not allow full use of the cassette." Assuming you own the same model, that is. http://www.lemondfitness.com/files/fetch/revolution/300223-RevolutionOM-RevB.pdf"

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still wondering about this, I recently picked up a Lemond Revolution, with the 10speed free hub. What I did to make it compatible with my 11 speed grippe is: on my 11-28 cassette, remove the 12 tooth cog, and add a spacer on the inside before the 28tooth, and bam. Shifts perfectly, no limit screw adjusting or anything.

Answer (score 2):

Get a [Campy freehub](http://www.probikeshop.com/en/gb/campagnolo-freewheel-body-for-lemond-revolution-1-1-home-trainer/101709.html).

Either you're running Campy already and there's nothing to worry about, or you're SRAM/Shimano and [Lennard Zinn says](https://www.velonews.com/gear/drivetrain-compatibility-hidden-in-plain-sight/) that'll work just fine too.